# What drivers do I need for reinstalling Windows 7 on a Lenovo 7510p?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, reinstall

I recently bought a 7510P PC (from Lenovo) with a GT755m SLI, 16GB DDR3 1TB+24SSD with Windows 8.

I want to re-install it with Windows 7 in a different language.

Where could I get a list for all the drivers I might need for the computer to work properly?

Comment: Your model supports Windows 7. The official [Lenovo support page](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS035829) provides all drivers you might need.

Comment: these are ALL the drivers for the pc? don't i need some more for the gt755m sli?

Comment: user2554080, possibly, but, do as per @and31415 suggestion first - and then only update the drivers if you have to

Comment: @user2554080 Laptops usually require specific drivers which are provided by their manufacturers. The integrated graphic card is a *mobile* version (in fact, the model name ends with "M": `GT 755M`), and the related driver is available in the page I linked (see the Display and Video Graphics category). NVIDIA provides a driver for your model too, but it's a generic one and it might not be fully compatible with your laptop. Additionally, Lenovo may not provide technical support for issues that could arise from the use of generic drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your Lenovo computer supports windows 7, you can visit the [lenovo-homepage](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS035829) to download the drivers you need. Also some PC come with a CD with all drivers on it.

Also for the graphics-card driver, you can visit their website and download the driver for your operating system.

Just check at the Device-Manager if all drivers are valid(No "?"-icon) and only install additional drivers, if something doesn't work as it should.